# Music Player Supporting FLAC

Tags: music

I would like to play FLAC audio files, on any platform, with any free or non-free software.

Preferably I would like to play them on a ubuntu/debian compatible Linux desktop with good gnome-integration. But I just want to know IF any device or desktop software can play flac files at all.

Comment: Nearly everything I have tried on linux handles flac. Your favourite player *should* handle it natively.

Comment: just see this too http://stackoverflow.com/a/22251269/3682599

Answer (score 2):

### [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

- Supports decoding the FLAC container format: https://wiki.videolan.org/FLAC/
- Is free and open source
- Runs on Debian, see [installation instructions](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-debian.html)

Note that FLAC is only a container format (AFAIK), so that VLC may encounter embedded codecs it cannot decode.

Comment: Oh interesting, I guess I'm far more ignorant about flac than I realized.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all music players with a decent GNOME integration will support FLAC, because they'll likely be using [GStreamer](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox) for their decoding. (GStreamer should support FLAC anywhere)

Try [Rhythmbox](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox).